# GetHashCode --- MDE 2003 to Python

Tags: python

How can I produce the same hash result from using GetHashCode in vb .net 2003  when programming with Python?

I am porting some code from vb .net 2003 to Python and need to replicate the same hash in Python that was used in the vb .net code.

Thanks!
Bob

Comment: what kind of object are you hashing?

Comment: "*need to replicate the same hash in Python that was used in the vb .net code*." You really shouldn't do that. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1), "the value this method returns may differ between .NET Framework versions and platforms, such as 32-bit and 64-bit platforms ... You should never persist or use a hash code outside the application domain in which it was created"

Comment: hashing a Unicode word to use as a file name.